# Can a 2018 Mac mini support dual 4k monitors at 60 Hz?

Tags: mac, display, mac-mini, graphics, 4k

I guess I need more of a personal experience answer. The specications say that a Mac mini can support dual 4k monitors, but are there any caveats to this?

I am planning to get 2 x 4k monitors and run them both at 60hz, connected through DisplayPort (I will get Thunderbolt 3 to DisplayPort adapters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the 2018 Mac Mini can support dual 4k monitors at 60 Hz connected the way you indicate. I have this setup myself. There are no caveats.

Note: You do not need an "adapter" as such. You just need ordinary, passive cables from Thunderbolt 3 to DisplayPort.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to elaborate on what I meant, the displays come with a DP to DP cable, I wanted to get a thunderbolt 3(m) to DP(f) adapter. But I've also considered getting a thunderbolt 3 to DP cable. I ordered one from this company, called QGeeM, do you happen do know anything about them?

Comment: Never heard of them. I use StarTech for this setup - works without problems.

Comment: No wonder, they're all Chinese companies :D

Comment: @hey_you StarTech is American, not Chinese.

Comment: I have also same setup. The mac mini 2018 has 2 thunderbold controllers each driving 2 of the 4 ports. Would there be an advantage of plugging each monitor in one of the controllers or both in the same controller? Or even one in thunderbold and one in hdmi?

Comment: There’s no advantage for the monitors as such - but if you’re plugging other stuff into the remaining Thunderbolt ports, and they’re very bandwidth hungry, then it would be best to plug each monitor into its own controller. That way the other devices won’t have to share the bandwidth of one controller.

Comment: What about the HDMI? If using this for 1st monitor and then TB for 2nd thats even better for bandwidth on TB?

Comment: Not really, no - using the Alternate Mode DisplayPort signal within the Thunderbolt 3  connector does not take away any Thunderbolt bandwidth. The advantage of using HDMI is that you'll have an extra, available Thunderbolt 3 port for use with other stuff (if you have something to connect that is).